# How to put multiple circles code in one function? or loop?

Tags: python, function, loops, turtle-graphics

```
from turtle import *

circle(60)
```

first circle

```
penup()
setposition(-120, -40)
pendown()
circle(50)
```

second circle

```
penup()
setposition(140, 0)
pendown()
circle(60)
```

third circle

```
penup()
setposition(260, -40)
pendown()
circle(50)
```

last circle

I just want to know how to put 4 circles in a function.

Comment: Is the problem that you don't know how to write a function or that something is wrong with those statements ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going with your "or loop" option, here's a simple approach, that could become a function, based on @MadPhysicist's comment which was lost when @OTTTO deleted his answer:

> Iterate over a sequence of three element tuples instead : coords =
>   [(60, 0, 0), (...), ...]; for r, x, y in coords: – Mad Physicist

I've made the data structure `[((x, y), radius), (...), ...]` but basically the same idea:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle("turtle")

CIRCLES = [
    ((0, 0), 60), # first circle
    ((-120, -40), 50), # second circle
    ((140, 0), 60), # third circle
    ((260, -40), 50), # last circle
]

for position, radius in CIRCLES:
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setposition(position)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(radius)

turtle.hideturtle()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from turtle import *

circle(50)
penup()
setposition(0, 0)
pendown()

penup()
setposition(100, 0)
pendown()
circle(70)

penup()
setposition(200, 0)
pendown()
circle(90)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more like to attract upvotes.